# Diferenciar entre mayúsculas y minúsculas dentro de un WHERE en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

En mi consulta SQL la tengo asi:

`SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE  usuario =  'Admin' AND contraseña = '123'`

El cual esta consulta me muestra lo siguiente:

Quisiera saber como puedo realizar una consulta SQL que me **diferencie** entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, es decir mi condición en la consulta es "Admin" que me traiga el  `id_usuario 1` y si la condición estuviera "ADMIN" que me traiga el registro  `id_usuario 6`. ¿Que puedo hacer?

```
|id_usuario| |id_empleado|usuario |contraseña |id_tipo|
_______________________________________________________
|1           |1          |Admin   |123        |1      |
_______________________________________________________
|6           |6          |ADMIN   |123        |1      |
_______________________________________________________
```

Comment: Sinceramente no puedo creer que Microsoft haya llevado el non-case-sensitive hasta este punto.... En serio te trae los dos registros? :-O!!!!!

Comment: @eftshift0 si :( y no se que hacer

Comment: Por cierto... como recomendación: **no guardes las claves textualmente en la DB** Usa hashes.... y si les puedes agregar sal, mejor. https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/difference-encryption-hashing-salting/#:~:text=Salting%20is%20a%20concept%20that,specifically%20against%20brute%20force%20attacks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831105/how-to-do-a-case-sensitive-search-in-where-clause-im-using-sql-server

Comment: @eftshift0 Muchas Gracias :D ya ahora solo me muestra el que necesito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer tu consulta sensible a mayúsculas/minúsculas cambiando la intercalación usada por la BDD:

```
SELECT *
FROM Usuario
WHERE   usuario= 'Admin' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS;
```

Answer (score 2):

Siguiendo el tip de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831105/how-to-do-a-case-sensitive-search-in-where-clause-im-using-sql-server sería

```
SELECT *
FROM Usuario
WHERE
    usuario = 'Admin' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
    AND contraseña = '123' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Insisto con el tema de los passwords: **no guardes passwords textuales en una tabla**, usa hashes o *condiméntalas*.

Update:
Para los interesados, tip de @Luis Cazares (mirar comentario): `Ya que andamos en eso, tal vez debería de usarse una interecalación binaria como SQL_Latin1_General_BIN que es mucho más rápida y estricta.`

Comment: Uno dice eso hasta que llega al proyecto / producto en el que el cliente mimado usa WinServer + MSSQL + ActiveDirectory. ;) (Además, MSSQL 2017 ya corre sobre linux y hay imagen docker... lo que no hace que funcione mejor, pero sí nos quita excusas)

Comment: Si me tocara, lo haría.... pero _por elección_? **nou güei.**

Comment: Ya que andamos en eso, tal vez debería de usarse una interecalación binaria como `SQL_Latin1_General_BIN` que es mucho más rápida y estricta.